# divider color for Grid View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

[image]

In below image, am using grid view and there is one background image. I have put grid view items semi transparent. Now I want dividers color white. How I can do this. Is any param for this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="your_divider_color"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp" >
```

In your case, `your_divider_color` should be `@android:color/transparen`